# Flowplayer plugin shows “HTML5 Video File Not Found” error in Win7:IE9 & Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, flowplayer

Flow player working on chrome browser but it's not support for Firefox and IE9. It display's HTML5 video file not found error, but the URL actually contain MP4 video.

Comment: I've used some versions of Flowplayer just fine in FireFox.  You'll need to link an example please.

& also un-tag html5 & javascript please; not related to a flowplayer bug.

Comment: I have this issue here - Firefox supports WebM though which I include: http://chew.tv/videos/watch/4B4794HYM7MD/GetDarkerTV-LIVE-192-XMAS-PARTY-2013

Answer (score 1):

This will likely be because the video format you are using is not supported in those browsers.

See HTML5 wiki [Browser support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support) for details

To get good support across multiple browsers you really need two formats `MP4` and `WebM`